# How to run Hive on Spark job from Beeline or any JDBC client?

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to run a Hive on Spark query (Hive query with Spark as execution engine). I have set this up in the hive-site.xml

I have started a hiveserver2, and trying to connect to it on the same machine using Beeline, as following:

```
$ hiveserver2 &
$ $HIVE_HOME/bin/beeline -u jdbc:hive2://myIP:10000 -e "select count(*) from item;"
```

but the job is not submitted, and I get the following wrror

```
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask (state=08S01,code=1)
```

The following are working fine with Hive on Spark:

Using Hive CLI:

```
$ $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -e "select count(*) from item;"
```

Using Beeline embedded mode:

```
$ $HIVE_HOME/bin/beeline -u jdbc:hive2:// -e "select count(*) from item;"
```

PS: `hive-site.xml` contains the following properties:

```
<property>
<name>hive.execution.engine</name>
<value>spark</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>spark.master</name>
<value>yarn-cluster</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>spark.eventLog.enabled</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>spark.eventLog.dir</name>
<value>file:///tmp/spark-events</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>spark.executor.memory</name>
<value>512m</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>spark.serializer</name>
<value>org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer</value>
</property>
```

Edit: Found this in the logs:

```
INFO  [stderr-redir-1]: client.SparkClientImpl (SparkClientImpl.java:run(569)) - ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException: User: root is not allowed to impersonate anonymous
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem to run Hive-on-Spark with hive-2.0.0 and spark 1.4.2. To overcome it, just add following properties to hadoop configuration file core-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
 </property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
```

good luck.

Comment: You may need to change "**root**" in property name to your actual login account name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ $HIVE_HOME/bin/beeline -n <username> -p <password> -u jdbc:hive2://myIP:10000 -e "select count(*) from item;"
```

Comment: Some sort of explanation should be given with this post or it will risk deletion...